# Inductances, open switch, arcing: What maintains the arc? EMF source or circuit inductance?

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

As we know, with an inductance in circuit, arcing will happen at switch contacts while opening the switch. The arc is created because of the circuit inductance.

My question is - **what will maintain the arc post creation, the circuit inductance or the power source?**

Please explain the reason as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arc will be maintained by the power source.

Although the inductor may stabilize the arc, it does not have enough energy to maintain it beyond responding to momentary current changes. So, you'll need a continuous supply of energy that could come only from a power supply, which, given sufficient power, can maintain the arc with or without an inductor.

Comment: Seems good. Do you have any citation or reference on same? Just asking to be on safe side.

Comment: @LPT I have not done any research on this specific topic - my answer was based on common sense, prior knowledge and experience. So I don't have any specific references.  Looking now, I can see that there is no reference to inductors in Wikipedia article on electric arc.

Comment: @V.P. I can't accept loose remarks no matter how convincing they sound, since not backed by credible source. Apologies for same. Thanks for your inputs. If I find some proper answer on same, I will loop you as well.

Comment: @LPT Arc is a current through ionized air with come finite resistance - it requires continuous supply of energy, $I^2Rt$.  The energy stored by inductor is limited, $LI^2/2$. Hence, inductor cannot maintain arc. You can read Wikipedia articles (or any other sources) on electric arc and inductor to verify these statements.

Answer (score 1):

From basic circuit theory, you can not change the current through an ideal inductor instantaneously. Consequently, when you try to open the circuit with a  switch, a high emf (voltage) occurs across the gap to try and keep the current flowing. Thus the arc created at the gap.